# R mapproj lambert-azimuthal equal area projection

Tags: r, dictionary, projection

How can I do a lambert-azimuthal equal area projection with the mapproj package?
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapproj/mapproj.pdf

There is

> azequalarea() equal-area

and

> lambert(lat0,lat1) conformal, true scale on lat0 and lat1

What one is closests to lambert-azimuthal equal area projection?

Answer (score 7):

In package `mapproj`, and the function `mapproject()`, it seems that the Lambert-azimuthal equal area projection would be `azequalarea()` since `lambert(lat0,lat1)` is the Lambert Conformal Conic projection (since it is listed in the manual in the `Polar conic projections symmetric about the Prime Meridian`).

In package `GEOmap`, the projection is done using function `lamaz.eqarea()`.

In package `rgdal`, it is done with a call to function `spTransform()` containing a proj4 string starting with `+proj=laea`.

Comment: Nice answer.  On anything but a very small project, I'd strongly recommend sticking with proj4strings for consistency and flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since I want to plot maps with ggplot2 I rely on  mapproject().